# When to call selectRow: on a UIPickerView that has just loaded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I am trying to learn iPhone/iOS programming. I have an UIPickerView that should dispay its selected row as soon as it becomes visible (it is contained on a flippSideView).

Unfortunately, the flipSideViewController's `awakeFromNib` is not called. It is  somewhat too late to do it in `viewDidLoad`.
So, how can I make the pickerView display the selected row as soon it becomes visible?

**Update:**

Here is how I show the flipside view

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    

    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.uData = userData;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    controller.pickerView.delegate   = userData;
    controller.pickerView.dataSource = userData;

    [controller release];
}// showInfo
```

In the flipside controller there is a method mySelect (to help me trace trace the calls)

```
-(void) mySelect:(NSString*) strMethod{
    int row = [uData getCurrentUserRow];
    [pickerView selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:NO];        
    NSLog(@"selectRow %d called from %@  (pickerView=%d uData=%d)", row, strMethod, (int)pickerView, (int)uData); }
```

and when the program runs it generates the log

```
selectRow 3 called from viewDidLoad  (pickerView=87412720 uData=89267696) 
selectRow 3 called from viewWillAppear (pickerView=87412720 uData=89267696) 
selectRow 3 called from viewDidAppear (pickerView=87412720 uData=89267696)
```

Comment: When or where are you adding the picker view that it won't exist at `viewWillAppear:`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I can see the incorrect selection appear for a short time.

Comment: +1,@Deepak, Sorry I meant viewWillLoad. It does exist in viewWillAppear!

Comment: If it exists in viewWillAppear, then select the row in viewWillAppear.

Comment: @thomashw, I call it from viewWillAppear (se my new update)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're having the problem i had a couple days ago, i really don't think it's a bug I think the problem is when everything is called (could be wrong). Correct me if I'm wrong but you want your PickerView to display a certain value when it's first shown onscreen correct? Are you creating the PickerView in code or from a nib?

In my app, the below code snippet is right at the bottom of my viewDidLoad method

```
[pickerView selectRow: 100 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

This works as intended.  Please post a snippet of your code so we can better understand your problem.

PS: When developing for iOS i would stay away from awakeFromNib and just use ViewDidLoad:

Comment: Yes, I like it to display certain values when first shown, but without any animation!! What happens if you change 'animated' to NO ?

Comment: To be honest it's loaded so quickly that you don't even notice the animation, although I am using Core Animation to make it rise from the bottom of the screen. But setting it to no just make's it jump to your value instantly.  Let me know if it's still not working for you

Answer (score -1):

There apparently is a bug in some versions of iOS that means your view is not loaded until you call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` or force it to load by calling `[self view]`.

Comment: Can you verify this? It's easy to point at Apple frameworks, but often you're just ignoring Apple's best practice. You're always supposed to call the super's implementation of the view lifecycle methods in your implementation.

Comment: I have heard this from a coworker. Maybe it's a bug, maybe it's not a bug, but I don't know any reason why the framework shouldn't load the view before calling -viewWillAppear:. Additionally, I'm pretty sure -viewDidLoad does not need to super-call (and in one of our strange class hierarchies it doesn't, for reasons which I intend on refactoring out...).

Comment: It was a misstake in my question. I have the pickView in viewWillAppear.  I call selectRow from viewDidLoad (which happens before viewWillAppear) but it is somewhat too late.